Does $cl_G(f(x)) = f^{\to}([x])$ for all $x \in X$?
Conjecture:
Assume the following:

$G$ is a finite group with an identity element $e_G$.

$X$ is a nonempty finite set.

$f: X \to G$ be a function and for every set $A$ denote $f^{\to}(A) := \{f(a) : a\in A\}$ (i.e., the image of $A$ under $f$). Moreover, at least one $x_0 \in X$ must exist such that $f(x_0) = e_G$.

$R$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by $xRy$ iff $\exists g \in G$ such that the property $f(x) = gf(y)g^{-1}$ holds.

Denote $[x]$ as the equivalence class of $x \in X$.

Denote $cl_G(g)$ as the conjugacy class of $g \in G$.


I want to prove for all $x \in X$
$$f^{\to}([x]) = cl_G(f(x)) \label{conj} \tag{1}$$
$\rule{405pt}{0.5pt}$
Attempt #1:
$\subseteq$: Let $g_0 \in f^{\to}([x])$, then, there is a $z \in [x]$ with $f(z) = g_0$. So, $\exists g \in G$ such that $f(z) = gf(x)g^{-1}$ (and hence the conjugacy class of $f(z)$ and $f(x)$ are equal) and $g_0 = gf(x)g^{-1}$. Thus,
$$g_0 \in cl_G(g_0) = cl_G(f(x))$$
Therefore, $f^{\to}([x]) \subseteq cl_G(f(x))$
$\supseteq$: Let $g_0 \in cl_G(f(x))$. Then, there is a $g \in G$ such that $g_0 = gf(x)g^{-1}$. Now, take any $zRx$ such that $f(z) = gf(x)g^{-1}$. This is possible because the conjugacy class of $f(x)$ and $f(z)$ are equal. Then, $g_0 = f(z)$. Note that $[x] = [z]$, and so $f^{\to}([x]) = f^{\to}([z])$. Hence, $g_0 = f(z) \in f^{\to}([z]) = f^{\to}([x])$.
Therefore, $cl_G(f(x)) \subseteq f^{\to}([x])$
Since $cl_G(f(x)) \subseteq f^{\to}([x])$ and $f^{\to}([x]) \subseteq cl_G(f(x))$, we have $f^{\to}([x]) = cl_G(f(x))$ and the prove is complete.
$\textbf{Q.E.D.}$
$\rule{405pt}{0.5pt}$
Attempt #2:
Here is an easier way to prove $\eqref{conj}$. Let $x \in X$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
f^{\to}([x]) &= \{f(z) : z \in [x]\}\\
&= \{f(z) : zRx\}\\
&= \{f(z) : \exists g \in G, \,\ f(z) = gf(x)g^{-1}\}\\
&= \{gf(x)g^{-1} : g \in G\}\\
&= cl_G(f(x))
\end{align}
$$
$\textbf{Q.E.D.}$
$\rule{405pt}{0.5pt}$
Question
Is this proof valid?

Not sure I am following.  Suppose $f$ is a constant, and that the image of all of $X$ is some group element $g$ with a non-trivial conjugacy class.  then the left hand consists of a single point but the right hand is larger than a single element.    Is that not a counterexample?

I'm not sure it is true - I think you need $f$ onto.

I forgot to mention something. Let me edit it. I forgot to mention that at least one element in $X$ have to send to identity group $e_G$

That doesn't cure my counterexample.  Say $x_0\in X$ is mapped to $X$ and every other element in $X$ is mapped to a constant with non-trivial conjugacy class.   Surjectivity, as proposed by @ThomasAndrews  might be enough.  At least, that assumption would cure my counterexample.

Does that mean that $\eqref{conj}$ is true iff $f$ is surjective?

Well, why not try to prove that?

I think it can be true if not surjective. I think the image of $X$ has to be a union of the conjugacy classes. Surjective makes that obviously true.
